# Regex to validate brazilian money using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, currency

I need to validate some form fileds that contain brazilian money (its name is "Real") using Javascript. It has the following format:

```
            0,01
            0,12
            1,23
           12,34
          123,45
        1.234,56
       12.235,67
      123.456,78
    1.234.567,89
   12.345.678,90
  123.456.789,01
1.234.567.890,12
```

My regex knowledge is weak, can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$
```

That says "1 to 3 digits, optionally followed by any number of groups of three digits preceded by a period, followed by a comma and two more digits."  If you want to allow the leading whitespace present in your example, add `\s*` to the front:

```
^\s*\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$
```

As @ElRonnoco pointed out, the above regular expression accepts leading zeroes (e.g. 010.100,00).  To disallow those, you may use this longer version:

```
^\s*(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*|0),\d{2}$
```

To allow numbers that have no decimal part, or only one decimal digit, change it like this:

```
^\s*(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*|0)(?:,\d{1,2})?$
```

If you want to find such strings inside longer strings rather than requiring them to match the whole thing, you can remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @MarkReed: one missing bracket in the latest regex: `(?:[1-9]\d{0,2})(?:\.\d{3})*|0),\d{2}` Question: What is the `|0` part in the regex expected to do?

Comment: @Joanna - no, the closing bracket is the one after the |0.  Which allows forms like the first two lines ("0,01", "0,10") which would otherwise be disallowed by the new regex since they start with a 0.

Comment: @MarkReed - makes sense, I misread the previous regex. thanks for explanation

Comment: @MarkReed, It works, but i need to improve just one thing, how can i define that values like "1" and "1,2" are valid?

Comment: @MarkReed, Works perfectly! Man, i don't know how to thank you! You gave me a great help! Thank you very much!

Comment: if you do not use dot in thousand number, this is the validation `^\s*(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.?\d{3})*|0)(,\d{1,2})$`

Answer (score 3):

I would give this regex a try:

```
\d+(?:\.\d{3})*?,\d{2}
```

What it says is:
- match digits until
a. a dot followed by 3 digits is found (and this step can be repeated several times)
b. or a comma followed by 2 digits is found

EDIT: 
- thanks for the comments, I forgot about the constraint for the first value
updated regex

```
\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*?,\d{2}
```

Comment: Note that this accepts any number of digits with no grouping.  So it depends on how strict OP wants to be..

Comment: As Mark states this will accept `12345.123,00` for example, as being valid

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Mark's reply:

Who needs "." in the string and not "," to count cents. And need find the values in middle a text :

```
(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\,\d{3})*|0)(?:.\d{1,2})?
```

https://regexr.com/61166